# Flutter : Saving state in a widget between Bloc transitions

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am using `flutter_bloc` to implement bloc in my app.

I have a screen which does multiple transitions. So multiple events are dispatched on different actions on the page and each state returned represents the state in return for that specific event.

How do I maintain state in my widget in between these transitions ?

For example, the screen has 3 buttons. Each button click dispatches an event and the state returns a piece of text. So after clicking button1, the state returns a State object with the text and the button is replaced by this text. Now when the user clicks button2, it returns another piece of text and it replaces button2. But when this happens, button1's text disappears.

I have a StatefulWidget with state which looks like this -

```
List<String> allTexts = List();
```

but updating this state is not working as calling setState throws this error -

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

How do I solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check possible call `setState` in your `build` method

Comment: you should not save state in the widget, instead save the state in the state model class of bloc

Comment: Definitely agree ! How do you suggest I pass around the value though ? I have multiple classes, each representing a new state. Is there an example I can see where all of these state classes mutate a single variable ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always emit the `State` with the text for all of the `buttons`. So when you click `button` 2, you receive the text of `button` 2 + all the `text` saved for `button` 1 and 3

Comment: The state is emitted one after the other. There are 2 classes called SuccessState and FailureState which get returned. SuccessState has a String field which holds the value. The main point is, how I can access the 1st question's SuccessState when the 2nd one is done ? I agree that we need to maintain a List<String> values, but where can this be maintained and how ?

Comment: You can add a `List<String>` to `SuccessState` instead of only one `String `field containing the current value. 
Every time you yield `SuccessState` you'll have the list with the values for all of the buttons, not just the one pressed